# Get list of languages in Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, locale, qt5

I want to get the list of ISO 639 languages, from `QLocale`.  I can use this code to get all combinations of language/country.

```
QList<QLocale> allLocales = QLocale::matchingLocales(
        QLocale::AnyLanguage,
        QLocale::AnyScript,
        QLocale::AnyCountry);
```

This is exactly what I need. I assume I can filter out the list manually, but does a better alternative exist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do either that or do something not nearly as nice (see end of this post) and filter duplicate languages from the list manually, e.g. if you want the ISO 639 language names:

```
QList<QLocale> allLocales = QLocale::matchingLocales(
            QLocale::AnyLanguage,
            QLocale::AnyScript,
            QLocale::AnyCountry);
QSet<QString> iso639Languages;

for(const QLocale &locale : allLocales) {
    iso639Languages.insert(QLocale::languageToString(locale.language()));
}

qDebug() << iso639Languages;
```

`iso639Languages` then contains the names of all languages classified by ISO 639 and known by Qt. Note that it does contain the name of the language (e.g. German) and *not* the ISO 639 code (e.g. de).

If you need the ISO 639 code do this instead:

```
QList<QLocale> allLocales = QLocale::matchingLocales(
            QLocale::AnyLanguage,
            QLocale::AnyScript,
            QLocale::AnyCountry);
QSet<QString> iso639LanguageCodes;

for(const QLocale &locale : allLocales) {
    iso639LanguageCodes.insert(locale.name().split('_').first());
}

qDebug() << iso639LanguageCodes;
```

One could also construct `QLocale` objects by iterating manually over the `QLocale::Language` enum and then parsing the result, *but* I strongly recommend not to do that, since this enum might change (it did for example with Qt 5.3) and then your application won't catch the new languages until you manually update the iteration range.

Comment: I was afraid that this would be my only option. I am thinking of using a combo box, from which a user can choose the iso639 code... but I also want the user to be able to write "english" or "german"... what can you recomend ? Using a QCompleter, will not let the "simple users" choose from a list. Do you have any recomendation?

Comment: Use a `QCompleter` and combine both e.g. build your set with something like `tr("%1 (%2)").arg(QLocale::languageToString(locale.language()), locale.name().split('_').first())`. This should then complete for both "de" and "german". Also note `nativeLanguageName()`, which might be a better choice than `name()`, depending on context.

Comment: Note that you need to set `filterMode` of the completer to `Qt::MatchContains` for this to work properly.