# How to get the language/country name in my system locale language

Tags: c++, qt

I'm programming  with Qt an application that must show the name of some languages as text. I have set my system locale as es_ES. That way, I would like to get several languages and country names in spanish. But, I can only get in the native language, or in english:

```
QLocale lsystem = QLocale::system();
QLocale lswiss("de_CH");
qDebug()<<"system "<<lsystem.name() << lsystem.languageToString(lsystem.language()) << lsystem.nativeLanguageName();
qDebug()<<"swiss "<<lswiss.name() << lsystem.languageToString(lswiss.language()) << lswiss.nativeLanguageName();
```

This source code prints the following text:

```
20:17:09.229 [DEBUG]: system  "es_ES" "Spanish" "español de España"
20:17:09.229 [DEBUG]: swiss  "de_CH" "German" "Schweizer Hochdeutsch"
```

What I would expect is that `QLocale::languageToString()` method could return the name in my system locale language, but it's not the case. I want to get names in spanish (español, alemán), but I don't know how to do it.

Can I get what I want without translating each language name with Qt's translate utilities? Thank you in advance.

Comment: That is not possible with Qt, I recommend creating a file that contains that information and read from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Qt's translation system to do it and, in addition, it's already prepared for multi-language applications, not only Spanish. The drawback is that you have to create the list and translate it (you may google for some pre-built table on several languages).

```
QString languageNameInCurrentLocale(const QLocale& loc) {
  return qApp->translate("locale_name", loc.name().toStdString().c_str());
}
```

As you don't have the string literals in your code you have to add them to the translation system manually. You can use [`QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/i18n-source-translation.html#using-qt-tr-noop-and-qt-translate-noop-in-c) to do it.

The initial list can be generated in pre-compilation step that iterates through all locales (as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26307729/get-list-of-languages-in-qt5) for example) and prints with such information (in this example redirect the output to a C++ file). Add the file to your project and update your translation files.

```
void printLocaleList() {
  const auto allLocales = QLocale::matchingLocales(QLocale::AnyLanguage,
    QLocale::AnyScript, QLocale::AnyCountry);

  for (auto loc : allLocales) {
    std::cout << "QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP(\"locale_name\", \"" <<
                 loc.name().toStdString() << "\");\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help you!